# SQL Procedures Error #1064 - Something is wrong with SINTAX

Tags: sql, mariadb, procedure

i'm trying to create procedures but i keep getting the same error and i dont know why, help pls

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_login_credentials()
    BEGIN
        SELECT "username", "password", "sim_number", "id_sch" FROM "credential"//
   END
//
```

#1064 - Something is wrong with SINTAX near '"credential"' in line 3

Comment: Justo remove all the double quotes

Comment: Does the query run if you execute it outside the procedure

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it runs if i do it like this : SELECT `username`, `password`, `sim_number`, `id_sch` FROM `credential`;

Comment: @SimonMartinelli but i already tried to do the procedure with that sintax and also dont work before and after each name is " ` "

Comment: Then remove the double quotes already suggested

Comment: @SimonMartinelli didnt work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating a stored procedure on the command line, you still have to use semicolons as the line terminators inside the `BEGIN ... END` block.

As was also mentioned, double quotes are used as string constants. If you really want to escape the column names, use backticks.

```
DELIMITER // ;
CREATE PROCEDURE get_login_credentials()
    BEGIN
        SELECT username, password, sim_number, id_sch FROM credential;
   END //
DELIMITER ; //
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this sintax and it worked

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`() NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER SELECT `username`, `password`, `sim_number`, `id_sch` FROM `credential`
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE get_login_credentials
as
BEGIN
SELECT username, password, sim_number, id_sch FROM credential
END